# adding image from NSImageView to Core Data ( Path url to Core Data and Image to Folder )

Tags: macos, nsimageview

I am new in os x programming. I am using swift to developing my mac app. In my app I am able to pick and display an image from the folder in my mac to NSImageView , but my goal is to be able to save that picked image to data model. Later i need to transfer that data over wifi to my iOS app that i created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in data model add attribute with type Binary Data. store data in NSdata format.